# Font Styles Bold,italic not working in pdf while using ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using irport 3.1.0, while generating preview from the ireport all styles(bold,italic) are working, but while invoking from web application everything coming as plain text.

i have tried with below properties in font

```
<font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
```

can anyone suggest me what are the necessary steps to take care while generating pdf using ireport.

Thanks,

Comment: Here's an example of a question that contains enough information that someone can answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39756538/59087 Please provide details about what you've tried, what's not working, what you're trying to accomplish, and links to resources you've read.

Comment: You need to use [font-extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jasper-reports/5773/font-extensions)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally, I did some fix for this:

```
<font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true" isItalic="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
```

By using `pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"`, I am able to see the fonts as bold and for italic, I have used:

```
<font size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Oblique" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
```

Comment: I question this solution, as when I use pdfFontName I get this in Jasper Studio: "The use of pdf font is deprecated and replaced by the font extension".

Answer (score 0):

I did a different way to solve the problem.

I follow this steps:
https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-fonts

I got the Arial font from the C:\Windows\Fonts folder and put it inside the iReport program. Then I exported it to a .jar and added it to my project, in folder **lib**. So the report was generated correctly.

See how it got in the iReport:
[image]